# SSIS Executing package failed

Tags: excel, ssis

I created an SSIS package that gets data from the database and writes it to Excel spreadsheet. Everything is done on Azure VM. Everything works fine when run from Visual Studio. Then I deployed the package and tried to execute from Integration Services Catalog. I am getting errors:

...

### Data Flow Task: Error: Excel Destination failed validation and returned error code 0xC020801C.

### Data Flow Task: Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER. The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "Excel Connection Manager" failed with error code 0XC0209303...

### Package:Error: The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine. For more information, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=219816

Package:Error: the requested OLE DB provider Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 is not registered. If the 64-bit driver is not installed, run the package in 32-bit mode. Error code: 0x00000000.
An OLE DB record is available. Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Components" Hresult: 0x80040154 Description: "Class not registered".

I did install Access Database Engine, as suggestred in the Microsoft page above.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you executed the package from the SSIS catalog, did you set it to run in the 32 bit runtime?  And did you install the 64 bit or 32 bit version of the Access Database Engine?  The **32 bit** version will need to be used.  If the the 64 bit version was previously installed, this will need to be uninstalled first as both can't coexist.  Then the 32 bit version of the Access Database Engine can be installed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try it and let you know.

Comment: May I ask, how I can set it to run in the 32 bit runtime? "Validate" has a corresponding checkbox, and when I check it, it passes validation. But I don't see such an option on "Execute"...

Comment: On the Execute Package window, go to the Advanced tab and you'll see a check-box for 32 bit runtime.